# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space When Download Huge File

Tags: java, spring-mvc, io, heap-memory

I am attempting to download over 100mb video mp4 file by using below code. But i am getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" while downloading.

Using jdk1.7 & Spring MVC.

I have refered below SO links but none works for me.

[how to download large files without memory issues in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106775/how-to-download-large-files-without-memory-issues-in-java)

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while downloading a large file from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277324/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-while-downloading-a-large-file-from)

Please help me to resolve this.

```
OutputStream outStream = null;
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    ServletContext context =  request.getSession().getServletContext();     
    String fileName = Integer.toString(fileId);     
    filePath = fileName+".mp4";

    File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    // get MIME type of the file
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0, bytesBuffered = 0;
    while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesBuffered += bytesRead;
        if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { //flush after 1MB
            bytesBuffered = 0;
            outStream.flush();
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (outStream != null) {
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your -Xmx value?

Comment: @Stefan.. I am running on eclipse. from eclipse config file - -Xms40m -Xmx1024m.

Comment: which version of Java you are using? If you are using Java 8+, trying fine tuning MetaSpace.

Comment: Using Java 1.7..

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?  Is it the same every time, or does it vary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454126/spring-boot-java-heap-space-for-downloading-large-files
maybe u use the ContentCachingResponseWrapper

Answer (score 2):

I tried below code with 500 MB file and did not receive out of memory error

```
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

String mimeType = "application/zip";
String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            "abc.zip");
response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

File downloadFile = new File("file path");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

int n = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

while ((n = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buf, 0, n);
}

inputStream.close();
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

and JVM settings are:

```
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
```

Comment: Amit.. You can able to upload video files.. These files will store java memory?

Comment: But I think your qs was related to download, so I wrote code per download. If upload needs to be done then need to think of different solution, and where i needs to be uploaded, also can we upload it in chunk?

Comment: Amit. Client is downloading a video in browser from server. I think my ram memory is low thats why this problem happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()`, not just `OutputStream.flush()`, and rather more frequently.

Comment: outStream.flush();  response.flushBuffer(); I have added this line. But still error happens